# GraphQL IDE doesn't show up in Craft Admin

Tags: craft3, graphql

In **config/general.php**, I've enabled GraphQL and headless mode like so:

```
"enableGql" => true,
"headlessMode" => true,
```

[The official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#using-the-graphiql-ide) suggest that there's a built-in IDE for testing GQL queries via a GraphQL Nav Item, but I'm not seeing that in my Admin panel. Is there something else I need to do to get the GraphQL IDE to show up? Thanks!

Craft 3.7.37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL support in Craft requires a Craft Pro license.

https://craftcms.com/pricing

Do you have one for that project? If you're just working locally, you can enable a trial.

Comment: O I feel sheepish—that was the problem. Thank you!